# Unselect every thing in ipython widget

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

In a `SelectMultiple` widget in iPython, is it possible to select nothing (or unselect everything)?
There doesn't seem to be any option like that in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Set the .value property equal to an empty tuple

```
def clear_search_vals(b):
    tester_sel.value = ()
    temp_sel.value=()
    site_sel.value=()
    pass_num_sel.value=()
```